# Add print("...") to "INSERT or IGNORE into" to sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following code which either adds values to a database or ignores it if it already exists in the database. How can I generate a nice message if the data already exists in the database, e.g. "Data is already in the table"? I have tried using the print() but it don't works for me.

Im using sqlite3 and python.

My code looks as follow:

```
def information(cursor):
    a = input("Please define a 'a':")
    b = input("Please define a b:")
    c = input("Please define a c:")
    d = input("Please define a d:")
   
    statement=f'INSERT or IGNORE into data VALUES ({a}, "{b}", "{c}", "{d}");'
    cursor.execute(statement)
    cursor.close()
```

***Edited***

```
def information(cursor):
    a = input("Please define a 'a':")
    b = input("Please define a b:")
    c = input("Please define a c:")
    d = input("Please define a d:")
   
    statement=f'INSERT or IGNORE into data VALUES ({a}, "{b}", "{c}", "{d}");'
    
    cursor.execute(statement)
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
         print("Duplicate")
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: Please never ever do something like that. Never construct database queries in the code manually, it's prone to sqlinjection...

Comment: As for the problem, check documentation to see whether cursor.execute returns some useful info. It should because that's the only place that could give any info about whether query succeeded.

Comment: Ok, so how should I do it? I simply wanna message if the data already exists in database.

Comment: Check to see if a status code is returned by the cursor.execute and then use an if statement to match for the code. Again reiterating what @h4z3 said about not constructing manual queries, massive security hazard.

Comment: Is it possible to combine cursor execute with both the statement and a conditional print()-expression?

Comment: Yes, if the execute statement returns any form of code, you can place the execute statement in a conditional. The issue is that you're using insert or ignore which will ignore any values already present, you could use an insert and check for an error code which indicates that there is a repeated value.

Comment: Would it be better if I used Inser or replace?

Comment: Code you provide some pseudocode, so I understand how you are thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [cursor attribute rowcount](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount). **After the execute**, test the value of `cursor.rowcount` and generate an appropriate message. rowcount will be 1 if INSERT was successful, otherwise 0.

Comment: How can I implement this in practice: See edited question above.

Comment: `rowcount` attribute will be set _after_ query execution.

Comment: Could you illustrate in the edited code above?

Comment: I tried to read the link you added but I didn't find any good example of the correct implementation.

Comment: Ok, so now I put the cursor.rowcount() after the execute. Is that correct?

Comment: I have edited the answer to further elucidate the suggestion.

Comment: Sure,I understand that cursor.rowcount should be directly after the cursor.execute(statement). It's the testing part I'm insecure about. The edited code I wrote above didn't generate the print-statement.

Comment: When using the code above, it simply ignores but  do not print the  "Duplicate"-statement.

Comment: Now, it workerd for me! Thanks for your help. :)